# Can't understand how to load Spinner with different items each time dynamically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to load a spinner/ drop-down list with different items based on the category that was chosen through the navigation drawer, in addition to that it must be dynamically based on the amount and values of string that are related to each category.

I already have the strings and those are constantly changing by people actions online.

I have the strings, I know how to access those each time, But what I can't realize after searching through the web for hours, is simply that:
How to load the same spinner with different strings and different amount of string each time, without any constant values?

Sorry if this question is "dumb", I hope you could help, Thank you!

this is what I tried, from an example online but I got an error on "this" where I wrote "Already got an error here".
This isn't what I wanted but it was a start, this didn't work though...

Update: I will explain everything so you could understand better because I realize I wasn't clear...
Okay I have a PHP website (based on WordPress if that matters to you), and people can upload post and choose tags, I save those tags in an xml file with the entire posts data through a service that's refreshes every time the app is created.

The thing is, people are creating new tags, so I have new strings and items to choose to deal with.
I know and can access those tags easily, but I want to make a dropdown of those tags.

Each category from menu deals with a different JSON and contains different tags, I want make an asynctask that check which post contains the selected tag, that I know how to do.

But I don't know how to fill the list with different tags, so when I will press on one option in the dropdown list, it will send the asynctast its value.
How can I do that?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,  View.OnClickListener {


Spinner spinner;
EditText searchFor;
Button SearchButton;
String[] itemsToChoose;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,itemsToChoose);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); //Already got an error here

    searchFor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
    SearchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    SearchButton.setOnClickListener(this);



    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);

    Intent intentLogin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivityU.class);
    startActivityForResult(intentLogin, 0);
    firstLogin = false;
    sp=getSharedPreferences("JsonData", 0);
    check = sp.getString("trompim", null);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}



public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

  

    }
}
```

Comment: You pass an arraylist to the spinner's adapter. Change the content of the arraylist based on your logic and then call notifydatasetchanged on the adapter. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `spinner.setAdapter()`? Descriptions are no good for others to understand your issue. Please show some code?

Comment: I posted some of it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here it is

```
List<String> timeSlots = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adp;
Spinner spinnerTime;
```

my arrayList of data

```
  if (hour >=9 && hour <11){
        timeSlots.add("XYZ");
    }

    else if (hour >= 11 && hour < 13){
        Log.d(TAG ,"Condition 1");
           timeSlots.add("YZa");
           timeSlots.add("XZa");
    }
    else if ( hour >= 13 && hour <15){
        Log.d(TAG ,"Condition 2");
        timeSlots.add("YZa");
        timeSlots.add("XZa");
        timeSlots.add("YZaZ");
    }


adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, timeSlots);
spinnerTime.setAdapter(adp);
```

So you just have to set the data to `adapter`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how do I fill the Spinner based on the If and Else conditions? and Thank you so much!

Comment: please check the edited answer , add the values , and then set the adapter

Comment: Okay, and then I could make a while loop in each condition and fill it with my strings. and another thing by writing "timeslots.remove" can I remove previos data? thank you!

Comment: yes you can use `timeslots.add()` to add the data and then `timeslots.remove()` to remove the data